# savebox for more complicated examples

Tags: boxes

I have a repeated section of text that I'd like to use `\savebox` for.  I discovered that `\savebox` has a limitation of one paragraph (see MWE below).

What are my best options for `\savebox`-like commands for more complicated bits of text?  For example, multiple paragraphs, minipages, etc.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{article}
\begin{document}

{This is a paragraph.}

{This is another paragraph.}

\newsavebox{\temp}
\sbox{\temp}
{
{This is a paragraph.}

{This is another paragraph.}
}
\usebox{\temp}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`\sbox` accepts paragraphs in its argument but it is a horizontal box like `\mbox` so you need a nested `\parbox`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{article}
\begin{document}

{This is a paragraph.}

{This is another paragraph.}

\newsavebox{\temp}
\sbox{\temp}{%
\parbox{\textwidth}{%
This is a paragraph.

This is another paragraph.
}}

\noindent\usebox{\temp}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, `\long\def\something#1{#1}` is close to your expectations, as you are expecting structures longer than one paragraph. Please remember however, that if an argument is too long, it may overfull the memory.